# Extract value from a property into another one

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am passing my @ObservableObject to sub views. Since not every subcomponents needs all the value from the @ObservableObject, I want to to extract certain values into variables which will then be needed for displaying UI to the user.

Imagine I have a Data class.

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageName: String
    @Published var label: String
    @Published var value: String

    init(imageName: String, label: String, value: String) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Now, this is what I want to achieve:

```
struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Data

    @State var foo = data.value

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(foo)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to do this, the compiler complains with the following:

> Cannot use instance member 'data' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

I need the foo property to have the @State, since that should be a value that needs to be count down to zero. Is there a way I can bypass this and still use the value in order to count down?

Comment: Couldn't your Observable object contain a variable that is itself an observable object and that is passed instead to the subview?

Comment: Maybe that would work. The data.value is just an abstraction. In my case it's a bit nested inside it. Also making it observable feels like I am doing something only for the sake of this issue. There should be a "cleaner" solution I hope..

Comment: Why can’t the `value` property be @Published?

Comment: The value is actually @Published. I will edit my original post. Thought its going to make things easier, when the example is clean.

Comment: Then I don’t understand why you need a separate @State property. Why can’t you use `value` directly?

Comment: The value is also used in other views. And it should be configured in those views. In this particular view the value should not be changed but used it as a kind of reference. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Aleks, when you declare a property as `@State`, you're basically saying: this view "owns" this property - i.e. this is the source of truth for this property value. At this point it becomes independent. That's fine, but you need to decide at what point this value is set (or re-set, depending if you need). For example, you could do this in `.onAppear`. How are changes in `data.value` affect (if at all) the `foo` property?

Comment: pass it down by putting `@Binding var value: String` in the `ChildView` then you pass it with something like `ChildView(foo: $data.value)`

Answer (score 0):

To access the value, simply use `data.value`. Your view code will look like this:

```
struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Data

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(data.value)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you ever need to get the `Binding` value of `data.value`, you can just use `$data.value`. Example:

```
TextField("Data value", text: $data.value)
```